# Not able to find the href tag from string collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code....

```
   $(lines[i]).find('[href]').each(function () {
        checkLinkFooter = true;
        footerLinks += $(this).attr('href') + '~';
        });                   And my string is : If you prefer not to receive, reply to   the sender or        contact us at <a target="_blank" href="mailto:tmcustomerresponse@agi.com" style="font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;color:#0085d5">tmcustomerresponse@agi.com</a>. Getting console error " Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"
```

Comment: try lines[i] instead of $(lines[i])

Comment: There was HTML in the string, the editor just removed it though.

Comment: C-link: this is perfectly fine jquery usage. It will return an object that is a jquery-aware array.

Comment: Make sure if the find [href] really suits your need. Either u wanna find the a-tag and get the .attr('href'), or you want to find the href ATTRIBUTE but then u won't have the .attr('href') inside the href-attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap your string with another dom object to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Now you have a string starting with a word, so jQuery will consider it as a selector, but since it contains invalid characters, it might throw an error saying something like `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hi <a>`.

```
$('<div />', {
    html: lines[i]
}).find('[href]').each(function () {
    checkLinkFooter = true;
    footerLinks += $(this).attr('href') + '~';
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CcTND/)

Comment: it is the value of innerHTML attribute for the new div element

Comment: @win Then accept the answer, there you'll see right sign .